# Failed to save keras model when tf.summary.scalar is used

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**System information**

- OS: Linux
- Python Version: 3.6.8
- Tensorflow Version: 2.6.0

I'm experiencing the issue that `tf.keras.Model.save` raises error when `tf.summary` is used inside of `call` function. A short script for reproducing the problem:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np


sw = tf.summary.create_file_writer('./logs/')
sw.set_as_default()


class Mymodel(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(64) for _ in range(3)
        ] + [layers.Dense(1)])
    
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        tf.summary.scalar(name='avg_1', data=tf.reduce_sum(inputs), step=0)
        return self.l(inputs)

m = Mymodel()
m.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
m.fit(np.random.randn(1000, 20), np.random.randn(1000), epochs=5)

m.save('/tmp', save_format='tf')


AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references untracked resource Tensor("1423:0", shape=(), dtype=resource). TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be tracked by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly.

Trackable Python objects referring to this tensor (from gc.get_referrers, limited to two hops):
```

everything works fine if I comment out the `tf.summary.scalar` line.

Any help will be really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `call` method is wrapped in a `tf.function` and `tf.summary.scalar` is not being tracked. Furthermore, all variables in your model should be trackable when you want to save it. One viable option would be to use a custom training loop:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sw = tf.summary.create_file_writer('./logs/')
sw.set_as_default()

class Mymodel(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64) for _ in range(3)
        ] + [tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])
    
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        return self.l(inputs)

m = Mymodel()
mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

@tf.function
def train_step(model, batch):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = model(x)
        loss = mse(y, y_hat)
        tf.print('Total loss: ', loss)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

epochs = 2
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.random.randn(1000, 20), np.random.randn(1000))).batch(32)
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataset):
      train_step(m, batch)
      tf.summary.scalar(name='avg_1', data=tf.reduce_sum(batch[0]), step=0)

m.save('/tmp', save_format='tf')
```

Check this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, so if I understand correctly,  that means `tf.summary.scalar` does not work with `model.fit` API ?

Comment: Not directly, I think you would also be able to use a Callback. You just have to understand that `tf.summary.scalar` is metadata that is not being tracked by `@tf.function`